# Using MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH converted to integers for a versionCode in the Android Manifest

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am looking for ways to version my Android App. I would like to not get confused over which version number I use so I am considering this:

```
Version Name: 0.1.2   Version Code:    102
Version Name: 1.1.0   Version Code: 101000
Version name: 2.0.0   Version Code: 200000

etc
```

Does this seem like a reasonable way to set the version code or should I just stick with an incremental integer which I am concerned might get confusing for me if I forget which version is which?

Comment: We used to have incremental integers in my company and never could easily associate a version code to a name. Since then we switched to a scheme very similar to what you describe and things got much better. This is of course personal opinion. Careful though if you put the app on the play store there is a maximum version number: you can read it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your question, I believe the problem to solve here is that you don't want to get confuse which version name is mapped to which version code in case you forget.

In short to help you **Google Play console**, already shows which version has which version code. Hence no need to remember it. This is already taken care by Google play console.

To make your release easier to identify in the Play Console, add a release name that's meaningful to you, like an internal code name ("Banana" or "Super Bowl").

[image]

let's further understand their usages:

1. **Version Name** - a string used as version number that is shown to user. The versionName has no purpose other than to be displayed to users. I recommend to **keep it simple**. For example minor releases like 1.1.0 and for major release it is 2.0.0.
2. **Version Code** - A positive integer used as an internal version number. This number is used only to determine whether one version is more recent than another, with **higher numbers indicating more recent versions**. This is not the version number shown to users. This should be **incremental**.

Answer (score 5):

Like every open question in the world, this depends on your personal use, so I'm going to explain what I've been doing in different projects I worked on and how it feels:

**Incremental number**: It's the simplest and most straightforward solution. Mostly all early projects start with this. If you have the version code, is not easy to know which is the version name. If you started in 1, it will be hard to reach the limit (2100000000). You will need to increment this manually, independently of the versionName.

**Mapping name to int**: Any function like `f(M,m,h) = 10^6 * M + 10^4*m + 10^2*h`. This looks so clever, because you can easily identify your version name from your versionCode. But depending on how fasts your versionName changes and the weight of each variable in the mapping function, it might overlap and create confusion. And also might be easier to reach the Play Store limit. Ideally you just need to change the version name and you'll have a function that calculates the version code.

**Commit number**: Just use `git rev-list HEAD --count`. This won't map to the version name neither, but gives more info of the number of commits in your repo when the apk was created. You don't need to handle it manually, and also will be hard to reach the limit. If you commit anything, it will increase even if you don't change the version name. If you build in a CI you will need to clone the whole repo instead of depth 1, and it might make your gradle build slightly slower to calculate it (less than 0.1 secs for 10K commits).

In my personal experience, it's so weird to just know the versionCode and need guess the versionName. For me the versionCode is just a number you need to increment for your releases, so the easiest and more automatic system you get for it, the better. Personally I like a lot the commit solution, because you should not need to upload any new apk without doing a new commit, so is really useful and you don't need to increment it manually.

Ideally you will just be interested in the **version name**. You should make sure it makes sense and it helps you. You can just use [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) or create your own system as long you set clear rules and helps you identifying the code you ship.

Comment: Great answer! Another option is to use a build number provided by the CI, if available. There are potential drawbacks, but for small projects built on a CI that is well maintained and unlikely to change, it's a viable option.

Comment: I can second trying to avoid calculating the version code from the version name. One project I inherited ran into a problem when the version code for version 3.0.0 was calculated to be the same as that for the previously released version 2.10.0.

Comment: I've never used or considered using the CI build number, but it's a quite interesting approach since you don't need to care about it and will be increasing naturally :). However, this is a really external dependency and is easy to change it as the project/company growths (you don't have the same CI requirements when your team is just 1 mobile dev than when there are 20 developers working in the same codebase). So you would end up adding magic offset numbers whenever change your CI platform.